# Angular 1.5 Component Host Element Attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to be able to set custom attributes on the host element for Angular 1.5 components.

Why?

- I want to add a class to a component so I can style it. For example, if a component's parent has `display: flex` set, I'll likely want to set the `flex` property on the component.
- It's often useful to conditionally apply a class depending on a component's state.
- In certain circumstances, I'd like to use ARIA attributes to make a component more accessible.

Here's a simplified example of what I'd like to do (it obviously doesn't work, but I'm looking for something similar):

```
angular.module("app").component('hello', {

  attributes() {
    return {
      class: "hello " + (this.greeting ? "hello--visibile" : ""),
      data-greeting: this.greeting
    }
  },

  bindings: {
    greeting: "<",
  }
})
```

It looks like Angular 2.0 [supports this feature](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1008), but I don't see anything in the docs about supporting it in 1.5. Is there a way to accomplish this for those of us still stuck using `.component`?

In the past, I would have simply used `replace: true` to solve this problem, but that's been deprecated and isn't even available for `.component`.

Comment: .component is not made for dom manipulation. If you want to control html elements you should use a directive instead (link function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mention, it is not directly possible as you describe. An attributes property would be usefull, but does not exist as of yet.

A possible work-around would be to use `$element` inside your controller. This passes a jQuery element as a dependency, so you can add attributes as needed.

```
angular
    .module('myComponent', [])
    .component('myComponent', {
        bindings: {
                greeting: '<'
        },
        controller: function($element) {
                $element.addClass('hello-world');
                $element.attr('aria-hidden', true);
                $element.data('my-greeting', this.greeting);
        },
        template: 'Define your template here.'
    });
```

The `<myComponent>` element would now have a `hello-world` class and a `aria-hidden` attribute. It is even possible to use bindings, as described above with `greeting`.

The angular component definition is [just a wrapper around normal directives](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/#sourcecode-for-comparison).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't realize I had access to `$element` inside of components. I'll probably write a quick reusable helper that grabs my attributes and appends the to the element.

Comment: Let´s say that you use this on all components in a project.. is there any downsides? Perhaps some performance loss?

Comment: How can I set host element style dynamically (for example width or height) ?

Comment: Found it. You can  use `$element.css("width", "50px")` to set element width dynamically to 50px.